# Ubuntu Dell XPS 15 - external display image not showing

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell, display-resolution, xrandr, xps

I have Dell XPS 15 9570 4k Ti and Dell S series 32 2560x1400 monitor. I have Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel 5.0.5-050005-generic. Im using HDMI that came with the monitor to connect with my laptop, but im not able to see image on the monitor when the resolution of the monitor is greater than 1920x1080, or 2560x1400(the monitor highest resolution). It turns black and shows "No signal from your device".

If i change the monitor resolution to 1920x1080 it starts working but it is very big. I can't use two windows side by side.

I have been searching for solution for the past 30 days but i didn't find any solution. I probably have searched the internet related to this. I really don't know what to do. I'm very frustrated now.

Note that I works with Windows 10 at full resolution. No problem.

```
$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 6400 x 2160, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
2560x1440     59.99 +  59.99    59.96    59.95  
3840x2160     60.00*+  59.98    59.97  
3200x1800     59.96    59.94  
2880x1620     59.96    59.97  
2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
2048x1536     60.00  
1920x1440     60.00  
1856x1392     60.01  
1792x1344     60.01  
2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
1600x1200     60.00  
1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
1600x1024     60.17  
1400x1050     59.98  
1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
1280x1024     60.02  
1440x900      59.89  
1400x900      59.96    59.88  
1280x960      60.00  
1440x810      60.00    59.97  
1368x768      59.88    59.85  
1360x768      59.80    59.96  
1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
1152x864      60.00  
1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
1024x768      60.04    60.00  
960x720       60.00  
928x696       60.05  
896x672       60.01  
1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
960x600       59.93    60.00  
960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
840x525       60.01    59.88  
864x486       59.92    59.57  
800x512       60.17  
700x525       59.98  
800x450       59.95    59.82  
640x512       60.02  
720x450       59.89  
700x450       59.96    59.88  
640x480       60.00    59.94  
720x405       59.51    58.99  
684x384       59.88    59.85  
680x384       59.80    59.96  
640x400       59.88    59.98  
576x432       60.06  
640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
512x384       60.00  
512x288       60.00    59.92  
480x270       59.63    59.82  
400x300       60.32    56.34  
432x243       59.92    59.57  
320x240       60.05  
360x202       59.51    59.13  
320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected 2560x1440+3840+574 (normal left inverted right x axis   y axis) 708mm x 399mm
2560x1440     59.95 +  74.99* 
1920x1200     59.95  
1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
1600x1200     60.00  
1680x1050     59.88  
1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
1280x800      59.91  
1152x864      75.00  
1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
1024x768      75.03    60.00  
 800x600       75.00    60.32  
 720x576       50.00  
 720x480       60.00    59.94  
640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
720x400       70.08
```

I don't have xorg.conf file.

This question is probably duplicate, but there are not any solutions.

Please please help me. I really don't know if it is graphic problem, kernel, display manager, or HDMI.

Please ask if you have a question. I could provide more information about the laptop and logs, but I too lazy and frustrated now.

Thank you.

Comment: On the amazon product page one of the reviewers noted that he had trouble using a refresh rate higher than 60hz. In your xrandr output it seems your are using 74.99hz. Try lowering the refresh rate to 59.95hz with a command similar to the following. `xrandr --output DP-3 --mode 2560x1440 --rate 59.95 --output eDP-1 --mode 3840x2160 --rate 60.00`

Comment: @J. Starnes thank you for the response. I have already tried it. The only thing that worked is changing to 1920x1080. At 1920x1080 it is very big. Thank you.

Comment: I have two other laptops and they work fine, but they don't have 4k display. They have less than 1920x1080. Also this laptop (Dell XPS 15)  works with Windows 10 without problem.

Comment: here is a bug report form 2016 https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93578

Comment: Have you tried a custom mode line with reduced blanking? See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1330392) over on superuser. Changing the cvt command to use the -r flag, `cvt -r 2560 1400 60`

Comment: Thank you for the response! Yes, I have tried it  and worked with 2048 x 1152 but not with 2560 x 1440.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this with the BASH script below, which I saved as `monitor.sh`. Don't forget to `chmod +x monitor.sh` to make it executable.

I don't recall where I got the script, save to say I've had it a long time.

Usage:

1. Run the script as-is, e.g., `./monitor.sh`
2. Take a note of the external display name you want, e.g. `DP-1`.
3. Re-run the script as `./monitor.sh <display name>`, e.g., `./monitor.sh DP-1`

That's it. For me the settings are remembered until I reboot and survive disconnecting the external monitor and reconnecting it.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo 'Missing monitor name'
    xrandr -q | grep " connected"
    exit 1
fi
MONITOR=$1
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00" 220.812 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1478 -hsync -vsync
xrandr --addmode $MONITOR "2560x1440_60.00"
xrandr --output $MONITOR --mode "2560x1440_60.00"
```